# How to unwrap child element using cheerio?

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am using node.js.

I am using cheerio html parser to read an html document.

In this example

```
 <div class="a b c">
      <a id="ddd"/>
      sample
 </div>
```

I tried this

```
  var cheerio = require('cheerio');
  var c$ = cheerio.load(/*html content*/);
  var cntext = c$('div').html();
```

`cntext` contains the desired div and all its children.

How can i remove the div and keep only the children nodes ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Solution with jquery**

> You can simply convert it to html element using $(HTML_SSTRING_VAR) to create a html and use .html() function to get innerHTML like in the first case 
>   can use

```js
var s=$( "#Div" ).html();
var temp=$(s);
alert(temp.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div">
 
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

**Simplest Pure javascript Solution**

> Just find the substring between last occurrence of "<" and first occurrence of ">"
>   which would be the content assuming that native javscript functions should work perfectly .

[Javscript Substring Function Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var s=$( "#Div" ).html();
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(">")+1,s.lastIndexOf("<")-1);
alert(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div">

<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

**Another Simple Way to do it**

> Just Create a div append the html content inside it and access the required content as innerHTML of the child div in the process we by pass the div which was to be eliminated

[innerHTML Documentation](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=innerHTML)

[Children Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

```js
var s=$( "#Div" ).html();
var temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = s;
alert(temp.children[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Div">

<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

> `.unwrap()`**Returns:** jQuery Description: Remove the parents of the set of
>   matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their
>   place.
>   [.unwrap() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

[ALL IN ONE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/423Lynue/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to select the `div`, rely on the selector method for that, and specific attributes of the node to distinguish the desired `div` against all others.

`$('div[class="a b c"]')`

see https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#selectors

you need to iterate direct children of the selected div,

`$('div[class="a b c"]').children().each(fn)`

see https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#childrenselector

you need to move each children found after the previsouly found `div`

```
$('div[class="a b c"]').children().each(function(index, element){
  $(element).insertAfter($(element).parent());
})
```

see https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-

you need to remove the empty `div`

`$('div[class="a b c"]').remove()`

see https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#remove-selector-

wrote on the fly, let me know.

Comment: If you insertAfter it will reverse the order of the children, it would be better to do insertBefore.